# Convert from an array to an arrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Ok guys this code is part of an assignment that I have, I am to implement an equals() method to check if two lines are equal, Two Lines are defined as equal if two end points are the same. However i can't check it because when i run the program as-is here, its blank as if the array list is empty. My question is: Do I need to change the loop reading through the file, or do I need to uncomment the initial array and do something with it in regards to the arrayList?

Any help would be greatly appreciate!!

```
    //Line[] lines;

    ArrayList<Line> lines;     
    Scanner reader;

public MyDrawing()

    super();

    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
}

/**
 *  Reads the file and builds an array of Line objects.
 *  
 * @param fileName The name of the file that contains the lines
 * @throws Exception
 */
public void read( File fileName ) throws Exception
{
    reader = new Scanner(fileName);

    //----------------
    // Change to Arraylist. Make the name of the arraylist "lines" so that code      in paintComponent works.
    //---------------------
    //Have to read the first number before starting the loop
    int numLines = reader.nextInt();
    //lines = new Line[numLines];
    ArrayList<Line>lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
```

Here i instantiate the arrayList

```
    //This loop adds a new Line object to the lines array for every line in the file read.
    while( reader.hasNext() ) {
        for( int i = 0; i < numLines; i++ ) {
            int x = reader.nextInt();
            int y = reader.nextInt();
            Point beg = new Point(x,y);
            x = reader.nextInt();
            y = reader.nextInt();
            Point end = new Point(x,y);

            String color = reader.next();

            Line l =  new Line( beg, end, color );

            //----------------
            // Change to make sure that you only add lines that don't already exist.
            //--------------------
            lines.add(l);
            //lines[i] = l;
```

and here i tried to add the line "l" to the list
            }

```
}


    if( lines != null ) {
        for( Line l: lines ) {
            int x1 = l.getBeg().getX();
            int y1 = l.getBeg().getY();
            int x2 = l.getEnd().getX();
            int y2 = l.getEnd().getY();

            g.setColor(l.color);
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

            System.out.println(l);
        } 
    }
    //Print the action to the console
    System.out.println( "drawing lines" );
}
```

}

Comment: You would get some help if you included a small example/only applicable areas of your code.

Comment: How have you tried debugging so far?

Comment: One mistake you are doing is, you are checking for available input once, and reading it 4 times.

Comment: Have you tried to print out numLines to make sure you can actually reach the statements inside the for loop? And also can you give a description on how the file you are reading from is structured?

Comment: Where do you compare the lines?

Comment: The file I'm reading from is just x and y coordinates for the two points and the color of the line. If I simply just uncomment the array and comment out the arrayList, with no other changes, the program runs, so I don't think its running through the loop properly so its not storing anything in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an instance variable named `lines` but you are not using it inside the `read` method. Inside the `read` method you are declaring a local variable with the same name `lines` and reading into it but that’s not changing the instance field with the same name. Hence that instance field will be `null` at the later time when you try to use it. Unfortunately you are protecting that code with `if(lines != null)` instead of asking yourself why something is `null` which oughtn’t.

While your code that iterates over the instance field works regardless of whether `lines` is an array or an `ArrayList` your code that reads into it cannot work with an array as arrays don’t have an `add` method. So, when changing the instance variable to an array, the fact that the read method still compiles gives you a hint that it is not using that array.

Change the line `ArrayList<Line>lines = new ArrayList<Line>();` inside the read method into `lines = new ArrayList<Line>();`. Then the list you are reading into will be stored in the instance field you are using later. And, of course, it won’t compile anymore if `lines` is declared as an array.